# Android studio drawing rectangle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, drawing, pascals-triangle

im new to app development and im working on my first android app and its gonna be a small app that will generate pascal's triangle [(Wikipedia page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle). It generates an ArrayList of BigInteger arrays and i wanna show that as a triangle. How can i draw these rectangles?

this is an example of how the arraylist looks like:

```
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
[1, 5, 10, 10, 5, 1]
[1, 6, 15, 20, 15, 6, 1]
[1, 7, 21, 35, 35, 21, 7, 1]
[1, 8, 28, 56, 70, 56, 28, 8, 1]
[1, 9, 36, 84, 126, 126, 84, 36, 9, 1]
[1, 10, 45, 120, 210, 252, 210, 120, 45, 10, 1]
[1, 11, 55, 165, 330, 462, 462, 330, 165, 55, 11, 1]
[1, 12, 66, 220, 495, 792, 924, 792, 495, 220, 66, 12, 1]
[1, 13, 78, 286, 715, 1287, 1716, 1716, 1287, 715, 286, 78, 13, 1]
[1, 14, 91, 364, 1001, 2002, 3003, 3432, 3003, 2002, 1001, 364, 91, 14, 1]
```

and this is an example of pascal's triangle:
[image]